# How to seperate common elements from different sublist and group them into a list in python

Tags: python, list, grouping, sublist

I want to group common elements from different sublists and store into a seperate sublist in python.

Example:

```
myList=[ [1,3] , [2,3] , [1,2] , [6,8] , [5,4] , [5,7] , [8,9] ]

outputList=[ [1,2,3] , [6,8,9] , [4,5,7] ]
```

as,
sublists, [1,3],[2,3] and [1,2] contains common elements
so we've made a seperate sublist for [1,2,3]

Comment: are they always pairs?

Comment: in the given list..we have the list of list of pairs..But iin the output list..we don't mandatory need a pair..we just need common elements

Answer (score 2):

You can use **networkx**.

```
import networkx as nx


# You list
myList =[ [1,3] , [2,3] , [1,2] , [6,8] , [5,4] , [5,7] , [8,9] ]
     
# Generate new graph
new_graph=nx.Graph()

#add your list as the graph edges
new_graph.add_edges_from(myList)

# Get list of sets of the connected components in the graph
outputList  = list(nx.connected_components(new_graph))

print(outputList)
[{1, 2, 3}, {8, 9, 6}, {4, 5, 7}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way without using external libraries.

```
def group_by_common_elements(seq):
    r = []
    for sub in seq:
        sub = set(sub)
        added = False
        for existing in r:
            if sub & existing:
                existing |= sub
                added = True
        if not added:
            r.append(sub)
    return r
                
print(group_by_common_elements(myList)) # [{1, 2, 3}, {8, 9, 6}, {4, 5, 7}]
```

If your expected output (number of groups with common elements) is very long but the nested lists are short, you could try to make this faster by storing each number and its corresponding group in a dict.

```
def group_by_common_elements(seq):
    groups_by_number = {}
    r = []
    for sub in seq:
        sub = set(sub)
        existing = sub & set(groups_by_number)
        if existing:
            group = groups_by_number[next(iter(existing))]
            group |= sub
            for number in sub - existing:
                groups_by_number[number] = group
        else:
            r.append(sub)
            for number in sub:
                groups_by_number[number] = sub
    return r
```

Answer (score -2):

i'm not uderstanding on what basis you are wanting the sublists.
but here is the code for getting all the unique elements from a list.
og_list=[1,3,4,2,1,3,1,3,3,1,2,3,1,3]
unique_list=[]
for i in og_list:
if i not in unique_list:
unique_list.append(i)
OR
you can directly use list comprehension.
.i.e.unique_list=[i for i in og_list if i not in unique_list]

Comment: Hello, I downvoted because this does not answer the original question, plus it would be easier to use set() to remove duplicates from the original list.